# Laravel methods

Tags: php, laravel, methods

It's more a "global understanding" question.

To save a model instance in the Database, we can use both:

SAVE()

```
$model = new Model;
$model->attribute = value;
$model->save();
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#inserts

and

::CREATE()

```
App\Model::create(['attribute'=>'value']);
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#mass-assignment

I supposed both of these methods belong to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model, but I have found only function save there:

```
 public function save(array $options = [])
    {
        $query = $this->newQueryWithoutScopes();

     //......

        return $saved;
    }
```

But I haven't found any function Create in that file.

**My QUESTIONS** are:

**1)** what is the fundamental *difference* between

```
->method()
```

and

```
::method()
```

(is the last one a query builder?)

**2)** *where* can I find "::create()" method declared?

Thank you very much!

Comment: In general, whenever you see `::method`, that means there is a static method which can be called without generating any instance of the class. This is about OOP. Not specifically for Laravel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. ::method() is static calling without the need of creating an object of the class beforehand. ->method() you have to create an object before.

   $car = new Car();

   $car->color = 'red';

   $car->save();

vs.

```
$car = Car::create(['color' => 'red']);
```

2. The create method can be found:

   \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::create

Comment: Thank you! Found it in \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder

Answer (score 1):

1)

`->mehtod()` is calling a Non-Static or Instantiated object method. Where as `::method()` is calling on a static public method of a *class*.

To help describe this in your context. Take a look at how `::create()` Operates. It returns an object that you can now use the `save()` method on after making changes. In the inverse, you cannot 'create' a model object from the `save()` method. You must have a model object first before executing `->save()`. Which where `::create()` comes in.

[Eloquent ORM - Laravel : Insert, Update, Delete](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#insert-update-delete)

2)

the create method is declared, I believe, in a higher level.

Comment: Thank you, Zaky! your explanation of question 1 is very detailed and comprehensible!